# Can php echo back jQuery code and immediately execute it?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, authentication

I am a bit new to jQuery and PHP. My boss needs me to write a login system to protect a web page which shows the company's business secrets, which is just a single html/php file.

What I did:

I created the login system by ajax, php and MySQL database. In my login.html, I used jQuery to get the username and password info from the login form, and directly send them to login.php by ajax:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#login-form").on("submit", function(e){

                e.preventDefault();

                var username    = $("#username").val();
                var password    = $("#password").val();

                var loginData = "username=" + username + "&password=" + password;

                $.ajax({
                    method: "post",
                    url:    "login.php?",
                    data:   loginData,
                    success: function(backData){
                        $("#login-error").html(backData);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
</script>
```

and in my login.php, I originally tried using

```
echo "<script>window.location.href='pages/secrets.html'</script>";
```

to switch to the secret page if the login information matched, but later I realized that this was foolish, since this would show directly on the URL bar of the browser and people can just access this page by typing the exact URL, like:

```
https://example.com/secrets.html
```

So then I created a div with id "page-swtich" and tried to echo back this code to just use the load() method from jQuery to load this page at a div:

```
echo '<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#page-switch").load("secret.html");
    });
</script>';
```

and this doesn't seem to work.

So, is this possible? And if not, what could be a better practice to solve my problem? I've checked what vanilla JS code is behind jQuery's load() but didn't find any practical results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I could make a suggestion?

```
echo '<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#page-switch").load("secret.html");
    });
</script>';
```

This might be overkill. Your document ready is likely not firing since the document was loaded prior to this call. Simplify it a bit and just return the page...

```
echo 'secret.html'
```

And on the ajax success add the .load

```
success: function(page){
   $("#page-switch").load(page);
}
```

A different approach would be to just use `header("Location: secret.html");`, and you could set it to only redirect on success, echo data back on failure

Comment: You are smart bro! I think that definitely should work! Will try it now! :D

Comment: Definitely works and potentially answered the question as well.

Comment: glad to help :)